# BJT output of CE configuration

Tags: bjt

Since a bipolar junction transistor (BJT) in a common emitter (CE) configuration is not a linear device, the varying voltage signal will not produce a current of the same waveform as at the base, and hence the output voltage waveform is not going to be a multiplied version of the input voltage signal. What does that mean? If I want an amplified signal at the output must I use a current signal, not a voltage signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a low distortion output i.e. an output "shape" that significantly matches your input voltage waveform you will fall-short without several things: -

- An emitter resistor to linearize the base-emitter junction
- Moderate signal amplitude because large amplitudes will usually show much more distortion
- Negative feedback (you might not be at that point in your learning yet)

> *If i want an amplified signal at the output must I use a current
> signal ? Not a voltage signal?*

A current signal helps but this can be largely overcome by using an [emitter degeneration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter#Emitter_degeneration) resistor: -

[image]

This table from the wiki page describes the formulas involved both with, and without, the emitter degeneration resistor: -

[image]

Comment: Well explained ,Isn't a current signal can also cause a large variation in base  emitter voltage and hence make it non linear ?

Comment: @user215805 turn this around - if beta is not constant then using a current signal will not result in a perfect magnification of Ib in Ic. Beta of course isn't constant or linear.

Comment: The keyword is: Negative signal feedback using an emitter resistor Re as large as possible - at the cost of signal gain.